# migrate taxonomy term csv

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms, migrations

I want to migrate on my Drupal 8 website a file CSV which contains taxonomies terms.

Its a simple file with id,name.

I create a module:

```
name: 'Taxo Migration'
type: module
description: 'Migration taxo'
core: 8.x
package: 'Custom'
dependencies:
  - migrate_source_csv
  - migrate_plus
  - migrate_tools
```

and file : /config/install/migrate_plus.migration.migrate_csv.yml

```
id: migrate_csv
status: true
label: Migration test
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - krn_migration
migration_tags: null
source:
  plugin: csv
  track_changes: true
  path: '/modules/custom/krn_migration/data/test.csv'
  header_row_count: 1
  keys:
    - id
  column_names:
    0:
      id: Identifier
    1:
      name: Name
process:
  vid:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: migration
  name: name
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:taxonomy_term'
```

I active module, i verify that configuration is imported, i rebuild cache but when i check migration

```
drush migrate-status
```

Nothing is shown

```
$ drush migrate-status
 ------- -------------- -------- ------- ---------- ------------- ---------------
  Group   Migration ID   Status   Total   Imported   Unprocessed   Last Imported
 ------- -------------- -------- ------- ---------- ------------- ---------------
```

Can you help me ?